# order of operations for environment variables

Tags: php, environment-variables

I want to understand how environment variables are set and reset (overridden). I'm running Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) PHP/5.4.14 on a mac . My theory is this:

Environment vars can be set in bash, then they can be overwritten with httpd.conf preceding a VirtualHost directive that precedes php.ini, which can then be overwritten by .htaccess (if allowable) and finally by PHP

I tried the following:

1. **setting environment variable in bash:** I added `export ENVIRONMENT='local'` to my **~/.bashrc** file, restarted apache and did not get any output from `print_r($_ENV);` (in a simple index.php file at the root of my webserver). I also tried putting `ENVIRONMENT='local'` into **/etc/environment**, and restarting apache, nothing, as well as **/etc/bashrc**, restart apache. still nothing.
2. **setting environment variable in httpd.conf:** I added `SetEnv ENVIRONMENT 'local-httpd` to the end of my **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** file (but before I load other conf files, such as virtual host [`Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf`]). I now see the variable in the array `print_r($_SERVER);` but not `print_r($_ENV);`.
3. **setting environment variable in httpd-vhosts.conf:** I added `SetEnv ENVIRONMENT 'local-vhost` to my **/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** file in my generic directive that points to my default document root. I now see the variable has been overwritten (to local-vhost from local-httpd, so I know where the variable is getting set).
4. **setting environment variable in php.ini:** while searching for a proper place to put my environment variable, I noticed that `variables_order = "GPCS"` was set to the production value rather than `EGPCS`. I changed it, restarted my server and found that I was now getting output for `print_r($_ENV);` but not my expected custom variable. It also appears that I am not able to set a custom variable in this file. Please tell me if I am wrong
5. **setting environment variable in .htaccess:** I added `SetEnv ENVIRONMENT 'local-htaccess'`. This worked as expected, overwriting all other values that were set.
6. **setting / overwriting environment variable in PHP:**

```
    if (...) {
     putenv('ENVIRONMENT=local');
    }
```

I'm asking this question because I have a lot of local and remote testing servers, some of which may or may not allow me access to modify httpd, httpd-vhost, php.ini or environment variables. I want to understand what is best for those difference scenarios (shared hosting, heroku, local servers, etc)

I obviously don't know how to properly set the environment variable in bash in a way that php can use it, I'd like to know how to do that (as I think Heroku does something similar with `heroku config set...`)

Answer (score 2):

normally Apache uses the user www-data, which means, that you don't have to modify ~/.bashrc but /var/www/.bashrc.

Because:

```
$ ~www-data
-bash: /var/www: Is a directory
```